# Powershell: Rename all files in folders and subfolders that are named "cover.jpg" to "folder.jpg"

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory, subdirectory, file-rename

I have a folder called Music.  This folder contains subfolders for albums.  In each folder is .jpg file named cover.jpg which represents the cover of the album.  I want to recursively rename all files named "cover*.jpg to folder.jpg.

I've tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path O:\FILES_IN_PROCESS\!!FINISHED!!\_MUSIC "*cover*.jpg" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('folder.jpg')
```

And this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse O:\FILES_IN_PROCESS\!!FINISHED!!\_MUSIC | where {$_.Name -ilike "Cover.jpg"} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('folder.jpg')}
```

but I get errors each time

Answer (score 1):

Let [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) receive the object's from pipeline, this way the objects are always [bound by Property Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipelinebypropertyname?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) using their [`.PSPath` property (PowerShell Provider Path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.2) to the cmdlet's [`-LiteralPath` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2#-literalpath).

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'O:\FILES_IN_PROCESS\!!FINISHED!!\_MUSIC' -Filter '*cover*.jpg' -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName 'folder.jpg'
```